# Android HTTPS Connection Basics

Tags: android, https

I went through [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html).

I have some couple of questions:

**1.** What is keystore? And what and why I need to implement?

**2.** What is TrustManagerFactory and what is 'X509' in this context? Please answer is there is something else other than 'X509'.

**3.** What details should I know or consult for from my webserver application team? Do I need to know about the any kind of certificates or something else?

My problem scenario: What I am trying to do is to retrieve some XML string over network and it have to secured because it is little bit sensitive.

I am waiting for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to study HTTPS in detail to secure your XML. To use HTTPS, you mostly just need to get an official SSL certificate for your domain, and use it in your server. Then the HTTP client, either in the browser, WebView or Java HTTPClient, will know what to do with it.

Comment: I already have certificate. Do I need to use HttpsURLConnection or simply HttpUrlConnection will work?

Comment: HttpUrlConnection will work. See "Secure Communication with HTTPS" in http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Answer (score 0):

Read the Java SSL implementation, [JSSE documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html) for some basics and perspective.

1. A keystore stores keys or certificates. If the CA that issued the certificate of you server is trusted by Android (i.e., it is already installed in the system trust store), you don't need to mess around with keystores. It should just work. If it is not, you may need to create your own trust store that includes the certificate of your server if it is self-signed or that of the issuing CA if it is not.
2. `TrustManagerFactory` produces a `TrustManager`. It tells your app/system what certificates to trust. Technically there can be other implementations besides X.509, but in practice this is the only one in use.
3. See 1. Ask them who issued the certificate. Or simply access the site with your browser. If you get a warning or an error, things might get slightly complicated because most likely Android won't trust the server certificate by default either. IF not, your app should just work with an `https://myserver/sevice` type URL instead of an `http://` one.

Comment: No warning no error in my browser. Just a green lock sign. 

So does this mean that simple HttpUrlConnection will work for fetching the purpose?

Comment: In most cases, yes. Did you try it?